# Multiple Apps in the Same APK

Tags: android, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

We are considering package our app as 2 separate apps, as 2 separate processes, with 2 separate package names. Is it possible to package this in one APK?

The reasoning behind this  is that we're using FFMPEG and if an exception or error occurs on the FFMPEG side, the app dies with no Force Close prompt or any warning (just WinDeath).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An apk can not be used to install 2 different applications.

An alternative is to install the second application from the first application. During installation of the second application, a prompt will be shown to the user to accept the permissions requested by the second application.

You can add this block of code in onCreate so that the first application is launched without the second if that is a necessity.